# Adding logarithmic axis to PDF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have found this code that takes a table that produces a graph and adds log ticks on the x-axis. I have tried to use a PDF and add a log axis on it (both x and y to be log). I have tried hard but could not find a solution. Could someone help me, please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/log ticks with fixed point/.style={
        /pgfplots/log number format basis/.code 2 args={
            \begingroup
            \edef\pgfplots@exponent{##2}%
            \pgfkeysalso{/pgf/fpu}%
            % configure the style to avoid crap like
            % 10,000.2  or 0.000999937 :
            \pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{%
                fixed relative,
                precision=3,
            }%
            \ifdim##1pt=10pt
                \def\pgfplots@baselog{2.30258509299405}%
            \else
                \pgfmathparse{ln(##1)}%
                \let\pgfplots@baselog=\pgfmathresult
            \fi
            \ifdefined\pgfplots@scaled@ticks@x@arg\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfplots@scaled@ticks@x@arg}\else\def\pgfmathresult{1}\fi%
            \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*exp(\pgfplots@exponent*\pgfplots@baselog)}%
            \pgfmathprintnumber[#1]\pgfmathresult
            \endgroup
        },
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    scaled x ticks=real:1e3
]
\addplot table {
0.0001 10
0.001 20
0.01 15
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to go from a PDF looking this:

[image]

To a figure with log log axes looking  like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add e.g. some pictures for further clarification. For me it's not clear what you want because this code already produces a log x-axis. If the problem is, that you also want the y-axis to be log, just add `ymode=log,`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Another possibility to produce a log-log-axis it to use the `loglogaxis` environment instead of the `axis` environment. Then no `...mode`s have to given in the axis options.

Comment: @vogs Thank you both for taking the time to reply! My main problem is that the code uses a table to create the graph and on top of that the log axis. I cant find a way to do the same thing on a PDF.(i.e I have an empty PDf without axes and want to add them)

Comment: I don't see the purpose of that. I think there are some major misunderstandings. You yous latex to write the 'code' which then is translated and outputted as a PDF-file. Where is the plot you want to adapt from?

Comment: @vogs I have created and saved this PDF on Matlab. However because Matlab's axes look really ugly I want to create new axes and put them on top of this PDF! I think this is possible, isn't it? This is my first time using pgfplots so I am little bit confused.

Comment: Like I already said in my first answer, this is not a good way to do it because if you export the figure as PDF from MATLAB, it's basically a picture. If you just want to put axis on top, you will never get the right scaling. Hence, either you format the plot already in MATLAB (there are a lot of options to adjust font, font size, ...). If you want to have everything directly out of latex, export the datapoints from MATLAB e.g. as txt and read it in via pgfplots command or use the `matlab2tikz` package in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    ymin=1, ymax=100,
    xlabel={$W$ [eV]},
    ylabel={$P$ [W]},
    legend pos=south east
                    ]
\addplot table {
0.0001  10
0.001   20
0.01    15
};
\legend{initial distr.}
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From Matlab simulation I would use only data as coordinates in `\addplot` macro.

Comment: Thank you very much!